# React: How to use this.state in subsequent setState() calls? How to force an update to this.state?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a small application with which you can keep track of some game scores.

The game is played between two players. A player can score points but can also incur a penalty. Instead of substracting the penalty from the player's score, it gets added to his opponent's score. The opponent should also get the next turn.

I setup a demo that implements the above description: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ybLQvR

As you can see in the demo it doesn't quite work: when a player incurs a penalty he gets awarded the penalty, instead of his opponent.

This is due to `setState` within `setTurn` not being processed immediately. `setScore` still uses the 'old' state in which turn has not been updated.

I'm aware this can be handled by passing a callback to `setState` instead of an object (see the commented code), which takes in the previously set state. If I do that things work as expected.

However, I need the updated value of state (in this case `this.state.turn`) in the `addScore` outside of the `setState` call as well. How would I achieve this? I've tried `this.forceUpdate()` to no avail.

Should I wrap the entire function body of `addScore` in the `setState` callback? How would I then return any calculations based on `this.state.turn` from the `addScore` method should I need it?

Side question: why doesn't `this.forceUpdate()` work? Does it just trigger re-rendering the component without processing the state queue?

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: If you are really on current state to change the next state, then using the callback function in setState is the better way to go

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @CallumLinington. So if I wrap the entire function body into the `setState` callback, how would I return any values from within the callback body to the `addScore` method body? Say, I want to return a value from `addScore` when player 1 reaches a score of 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you're saying now. To my undestanding what you are trying to do is make sure that the setState method has been executed before another setState method.

Now the docs have this to say on the matter:

> The second parameter is an optional callback function that will be
>   executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered.
>   Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate() for such logic
>   instead.

So by their recommendations you should use `componentDidUpdate()`. So how is the question now.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)
```

That is the method signature. So we can see here that the previous state gets passed in, and we now have access to the current state via `this.state`.

See [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmWxKG?editors=1111) for the answer.

Basically - I turned the `addScore` and `changeTurn` into functions that were just snippets of the `setState`. This means we can combine them together with or state changes to make one atomic operation. And they can be reused without adding complicated default parameters for different scenarios.

Secondly, I added in functions which applied these methods in order to set the state. These are what the buttons use!

Finally in the `componentDidUpdate` function there is now a chance to apply actions based on the current action that is being executed. Do not add a setState for the default action, otherwise you'll get an infinite loop of updating......